# How to use the .css function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am a bit new to using jquery, the following should display a button, and when someone clicks the button, the font size of that button should change.

Unfortunately, the button does not change its font size, for reasons i am not sure of.

Edit:
this example is the same one as before with adjustments, it works but it will only change font, once the mouse has left the button's area or if the button has be double clicked.

The font should change on only 1 click.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".button0").click(function() {
    $('.button0').css('font-size', '43px');
  });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.button0{
position:fixed;
left:48px;
top:55px;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:8px;
font-weight:normal;
}
</style>
<body>
<div name="button0"><input class="button0" type="button" style="width: 148px;height: 72px;" value="Button"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by reading the basic tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make sure the document is ready—as in, all elements have loaded—before making modifications.

Wrap everything in this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

Besides that, your selector is looking for a `div` element with a class of `button0` when you're trying to modify an `input` element. Modify your selector to say `input.button0`.

Also, jQuery has a `$(this)` selector which selects the current element. In your case it will select the clicked input.

And finally, since you're using jQuery 1.7.1, I'll introduce you to `on()`. It's generally recommended to delegate events using this function. Instead of `$(div).click()`, use this:

```
$(document).on("click", "input.button0", function(){
    $(this).css("font-size", "43px");
});
```

More about `on()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 7):

By the time `.click` is called, the DOM hasn't fully loaded. You should wrap it in a DOM ready function.

```
$(function() {
  $(".button0").click(function() {
    $('.button0').css('font-size', '43px');
  });
});
```

Also noted its not a `div`.

Comment: np, tiny mistake on the posters part.

Comment: hi i have updated the code and it only changes the font if the mouse has left the buttons bounding box or if it has been double clicked. It should change on a singular click.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using div.button0. The element isn't a div. try just .button0.

Answer (score 3):

That is because the javascript is executed as soon as it is encountered; so it is executed before the button is rendered.
Change the order and it'll work.

```
<input class="button0" type="button" style="width: 148px;height: 72px;" value="Button"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".button0").click(function() {
    $('.button0').css('font-size', '43px');
  });
</script>
```

jQuery also includes a domready event for this, which means the javascript will be parsed before the button but will only be executed when the button is there. This way, you can still put the javascript in the head, if you'd really want to. To do this, just wrap the existing code in

```
$(function() {
  /*code*/
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Need to properly fire off the event for attaching `.click()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button0").click(function() {
     $(this).css('font-size', '43px');
  });
});

</script>
```

Note the class name `.button0` as it is NOT in a `DIV` as you previously used.

Answer (score 2):

use it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.button0").click(function() {
    $(this).css('font-size', '43px');
  });
});
```